# use required on the second input of a custom component with 3 inputs

Tags: angular

assume that we have a custom component that consists of 3 input field
I want to give the user this authority that whenever they used the required attribute on the component selector, we apply the required attribute on the second field of it.
another important thing is that I want the whole component to become invalid when the second input is empty. 
so there are 2 tasks:
first, transfer required attributes from a custom component to its second input field.
second, I want an invalid component whenever the second field was empty(when the component is required).

```
<mother-component
required
[(ngModel)]="x">
</mother-component>
```

it is worth noting that my component model is defined on the first input field
it means that my model is the first input but my validations should be on the second one.